rdflib converting a complex CSV to a Graph - chained objects
I'm fairly new to OWL and RDFlib, so my apologies if any of my terminology is off. I have a CSV that I'd like to convert into a knowledge graph, where each row becomes a sort of top level subject, and then has properties linked to it. While not important for the problem, the knowledge graph describes some biological assays, which is where my example "IRIs" are coming from.
EDIT: The structure of my CSV is:
Each row is a type of assay
Each column is a descriptive aspect of the assay. These can be interrelated such as an assay's endpoint value being one column, and the endpoint unit being another. They can get more confusing with things like endpoint standard deviation value and unit as two more columns.
my basic structure is:
assay1 a obo:assay;
    rdfs:comment "Some comment" ;
    BAO:has-endpoint BAO:endpoint .

what I would like to do is add:
BAO:endpoint SIO:has-value "5" ;
    SIO:has-unit "mg" .

and:
BAO:endpoint CHEMINF:has-uncertainty NCIT:StatisticalDispersion .
NCIT:StatisticalDispersion SIO:has-value "2" ;
    SIO:has-unit "mg" .

such that those additional triples are still associated with assay1. The idea is that each assay will have it's own values, but I'm not really sure how to implement this with RDFlib. I'm guessing BNodes are my solution, but would that mean dropping something like NCIT:StatisticalDispersion entirely?

you mean each assay would have its own endpoint and other stuff, right? In that case indeed you will have to add separate entities for each assay, e.g. I'd simply use URIs for the endpoint which contain the assay ID inside isntead of bnodes. For example, if you have the assay entity https://example.org/assay1 then you could maybe use https://example.org/assay1/endpoint or similar to make the endpoint entity unique to the assay.

If you want to put this as an actual answer, I would happily choose this one, because that is exactly what I was thinking without it being a fully formed idea.  I can even add an "is a"  relationship to that entity to keep that IRI associated with it. I just dislike the ambiguity with blank nodes, so this is a perfect solution for me.

Im guessing <assay1> is your csv-file and BAO:endpoint equals one of your rows:
from rdflib import Graph, Namespace, Literal, URIRef, BNode, RDF, RDFS
OBO = Namespace("http://your/namespace#")
BAO = Namespace(...)
CHEMINF = Namespace(...)
SIO = Namespace(...)

def main(csv_data):
  #initialize your graph with some info about your csv-file
  id_file = URIRef("assay1")
  g = Graph()
  g.add((id_file, RDF.type, OBO.assay))
  g.add((id_file, RDFS.comment, Literal("comment")))
  
  #add information for each row
  for row in csv_data:
    add_information(row, g)
  
  #print using the namespace shortcuts
  g.bind("OBO", OBO)
  g.bind("BAO", BAO)
  g.bind("SIO", SIO)
  print(g.serialize())

#These functions extract info from your row
def uri_from(x) -> URIRef:
  ...
  return BAO.endpoint

def extract_value(x) -> (Literal, Literal):
  ...
  return Literal(5), Literal("mg")

def add_information(x, g):
  id_array = uri_from(x) # in your example BAO:endpoint
  # alternative: id_array = BNode()
  val, unit = extract_value(x) # eg (Literal(5), Literal("mg"))
  g.add((id_array, SIO["has-value"], val))
  g.add((id_array, SIO["has-unit"], unit))
  # you use instead of NCIT:StatisticalDispersion a BNode
  statistic_info = BNode()
  g.add((id_array, CHEMINF.has-uncertainty, statistic_info))
  val_unc, unit_unc = extract_uncertainty(x)
  g.add((statistic_info, SIO.value, val_unc))
  g.add((statistic_info, SIO.unit, unit_unc))


I edited my original post to better describe my original CSV, not that it matters too much. It looks like you are suggesting using blank nodes. That technically works, but I was hoping to avoid blank nodes. I think they make it harder to understand what is going on.
Also, for future reference, your code is difficult to read since you switch between bracket notation and dot notation. It's also a little overly complex without being fully fleshed out (the extract functions are unnecessary). It would also be helpful to describe your overall strategy before going into the code.
